# I am trying to figure out how to do CCC 2021 J2 problem with C, I am stuck here because at the output, it is always repeating the name, how to fix it?

Tags: c, cs50

Here is my code, I don't know how to add specific range in C so I did it like that. Also, can somebody show me how to fix my problem? Thanks a lot!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int max_bid;
int i;
char name;

int main(void) {
    int N = get_int("rounds: ");
    max_bid = -1;
    for (i = N; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
        int current_bid = get_int("input: ");
        name = get_char("name: ");
        if (max_bid < current_bid) {
            max_bid = current_bid;
        }
    }
    printf("%c\n.", name);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem you're trying to solve? What is the input? What is the expected output? What is the actual output? It seems unlikely a name would be a single character.

Comment: We have *no idea* what a **"CCC 2021 J2"** is.   You must present the problem to us.

Comment: Do you realise that the loop `for (i = N; i >= 0;  i= i- 1)` will iterate for **N+1** rounds?

Comment: Do CS50 really teach you to use global variables? That's a bad habit.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- `for (i = N; i >= 0; i = i - 1)` will iterate `i + 1` times. You should use a standard loop `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)`.
- `name` should be a `string` read with `get_string()`.
- you should maintain a `max_name` with the name of the best bidder.
- all variables should be local.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int N = get_int("rounds: ");
    int max_bid = -1;
    char *max_name = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int current_bid = get_int("input: ");
        char *name = get_string("name: ");
        if (max_bid < current_bid) {
            max_bid = current_bid;
            max_name = name;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", max_name);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I found out where my problem are, I am new to C so I might have something going wrong. Now I get it. Thanks a lot!